# How to describe "the state of being close to death"?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-request

Today I heard the sentence:

> We recover stray animals from **near-death.**

But the use of near death seems quite awkward to me.

Can I use **near-death** as an adjective and make phrase like, **near-death state?**

How would a native speaker describe this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is awkward. I would not use "near-death" as an adjective. You could just say "We rescue stray animals that are near death."
In that use, "near death" is a prepositional phrase used as a predicate adjective.

There is also a word, "moribund", that means near death, but it's a word that doesn't connote being rescuable:
[AHD: moribund](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=moribund)

Not the same subject, but "rescue" may be a better word than "recover" used transitively.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the expression [*brink of death*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the-brink-of-something):

> We bring back animals from the brink of death.

Here’s a similar example in use:

> [Hermit crabs brought back from the brink of death](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VME2r9UCG8c)

Here’s [more examples of *brink of death*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/example/english/brink-of-death).